# Spring Cloud and Hystrix, possible to monitor 2 kinds of applications on a single dashboard?

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I'm actually trying Microservices using Spring Cloud. I have 2 kinds of applications (`mysolution` and `mysolution-identity-provider`). Both of them have Hystrix and Actuator enabled and provide information via `hystrix.stream` endpoint. I also make full use of Eureka, Ribbon and Feign for inter communication.

I'm trying to setup `HystrixDashboard` and `Turbine` on a separate server. Here's my `application.yml` :

```
turbine:
    aggregator:
        clusterConfig:MYSOLUTION
    appConfig: mysolution,mysolution-identity-provider
```

When I start the Turbine server, **it successfully finds the instances of my 2 applications by using `Eureka`.** But it only retrieves the Hystrix Stream from one of the apps (`mysolution`).

Here's the log :

```
EurekaInstanceDiscovery: Fetching instance list for apps: [mysolution, mysolution-identity-provider]
EurekaInstanceDiscovery: Fetching instances for app: mysolution
EurekaInstanceDiscovery: Received instance list for app: mysolution, size=1
EurekaInstanceDiscovery: Fetching instances for app: mysolution-identity-provider
EurekaInstanceDiscovery: Received instance list for app: mysolution-identity-provider, size=1
InstanceObservable: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 2
InstanceObservable: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
InstanceObservable: Hosts up:2, hosts down: 0
InstanceMonitor: Url for host: http://mac-mini.local:8080/hystrix.stream MYSOLUTION
```

Is there a way to make Turbine retrieve streams from both applications ? I successfully followed the Spring Cloud documentation until now, the the part about Hystrix Turbine (without AMQP) remains... cloudy...

Comment: does `clusterConfig: MYSOLUTION,MYSOLUTION-IDENTITY-PROVIDER` work?  You need each service in `clusterConfig`.  And you need to put the cluster in the turbine url `http://{turbine-hostname}:{turbine-port}/turbine.stream?cluster=MYSOLUTION`

Comment: Your configuration works. But the apps are showed in separate clusters. Is there a way to display everything in a single cluster?

Comment: Not using vanilla turbine.  It is possible using turbine-amqp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you post the first comment as an answer so I can accept it, as it answers my first concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the following should work:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: MYSOLUTION,MYSOLUTION-IDENTITY-PROVIDER
```

You need each service in clusterConfig. And you need to put the cluster in the turbine url `http://{turbine-hostname}:{turbine-port}/turbine.stream?cluster=MYSOLUTION`